# static_transform_publisher: tf vs tf2_ros

Tags: ros, roslaunch, static-transform-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When adding a `static_transform_publisher` to the launch file, we have two options:

Version1: Old style with `tf`:

```
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="link1_broadcaster" args="1 0 0 0 0 0 1 link1_parent link1 100" />
```

Version2: New style with `tf2_ros`:

```
<node pkg="tf2_ros" type="static_transform_publisher" name="link1_broadcaster" args="1 0 0 0 0 0 1 link1_parent link1" />
```

It is probably advisable to use the `tf2_ros` version. Can someone explain, why we don't need to specify a frame rate for the new version? Are there any other benefits of the second version?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/389976/static_transform_publisher:-tf-vs-tf2_ros/) by [ticotico](https://answers.ros.org/users/58821/ticotico/) on ROS Answers with karma: 212 on 2021-11-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For a discussion about *static transforms* I would like to refer to #q346664, which goes into quite some detail (and links to the relevant wiki pages/documentation) and #q324820.

As to the difference in command line arguments: as explained in #q346664, static transforms are not broadcast periodically.

If there is no periodic broadcast, the *period* argument is no longer needed.

> It is probably advisable to use the `tf2_ros` version

Yes, and for multiple reasons:

1. it significantly reduces the traffic (ie: messages/sec) on the `/tf` topic for typical usage scenarios (where many frames are actually static), and
2. `tf` is deprecated (and has been for a long time)

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ticotico](https://answers.ros.org/users/58821/ticotico/) on 2021-11-03**:
thank you very much!